# How to deal with Singleton along with Serialization

Tags: java, singleton

Consider I have a Singleton class defined as follows.

```
public class MySingleton implements Serializable{
 private static MySingleton myInstance;

 private MySingleton(){

 }
  static{
    myInstance =new MySingleton();
 }
 public static MySingleton getInstance(){
    return MySingleton.myInstance;
 }
}
```

The above definition according to me satisfies the requirements of a Singleton.The only additional behaviour added is that the class implements serializable interface.

If another class X get the instance of the single and writes it to a file and at a later point deserializes it to obtain another instance we would have two instances which is against the Singleton principle.

How can I avoid this or am I wrong in above definition itself.

Comment: Just for future reference, you can remove the static { } declaration if you change your singleton definition to: private static final MySingleton myInstance = new MySingleton();

Comment: Got more info about the [readResolve()] at this link http://lingpipe-blog.com/2009/08/10/serializing-immutable-singletons-serialization-proxy/

Comment: I recently heard a talk by J0sh Bl0ch here where he explains the reas0n behind using the Enum singlet0n pattern http://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLoKSeJT_PsoSohgFoNKU9jF3ZuNT4DsiW&v=pi_I7oD_uGI&feature=player_detailpage#t=1910s

Comment: The reason not to use `readResolve` starts at `28:52` in Josh Bloch's talk (linked by frictionlesspulley).

Comment: There are more problems with a Singleton pattern than the deserialization issue discussed here. Check out [singleton-pattern-pitfalls-alternatives](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/singleton-pattern-pitfalls-alternatives-mahesh-ramichetty)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use the enum singleton pattern:

```
public enum MySingleton {
  INSTANCE;
}
```

This guarantees the singleton-ness of the object and provides serializability for you in such a way that you always get the same instance.

More generally, you can provide a `readResolve()` method like so:

```
protected Object readResolve() {
  return myInstance;
}
```

Comment: readResolve() only works if Singleton class has all its fields as transient otherwise implementation is not attack-proof. https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLoKSeJT_PsoSohgFoNKU9jF3ZuNT4DsiW&v=pi_I7oD_uGI&feature=player_detailpage#t=1910s

Comment: What kind of attack @nanosoft means?

Comment: @CollinD could you tell, how readResolve() method guarantees the singleton behaviour what is internal working?

Answer (score 31):

@ColinD is kind of right, but his answer also illustrates why singletons don't really jell with serialization.

Here's what happens when you serialize an enum value (see [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/serialization/relnotes.html)).

> The rules for serializing an enum instance differ from those for serializing an "ordinary" serializable object: the serialized form of an enum instance consists only of its enum constant name, along with information identifying its base enum type. Deserialization behavior differs as well--the class information is used to find the appropriate enum class, and the Enum.valueOf method is called with that class and the received constant name in order to obtain the enum constant to return.

So any additional state that you attach to your enum values does not survive serialization and deserialization.

You could do the same thing yourself, by adding custom serialization / deserialization code to your singleton classes.  That code would need to either not record the singleton's state at all, or throw it away when the singleton is deserialized.  Either way, you'd put the logic into a `readResolve()` method as explained by @ColinD's answer.

Now, I presume that the reason you want to serialize singletons is that you want to persist their state.  Unfortunately, that presents a conceptual problem.  Suppose that your application has instantiated the singleton in the normal course of events, and then it deserializes some object graph that includes a copy of a previous instance of the singleton.  What can it do?

- If it deserializes the singleton normally, it violates "singleton-ness".
- If it doesn't then the application cannot access the singleton's previous state.

Answer (score 7):

The solution with enum won't work with Singletons managed by Spring, EJB, Guice or any other DI framework. It works only with enums, only because enum is treated specially by the serialization algorithm.

Firstly, *singletons don't need serialization*, because if you deserialized it, and then deserialized singleton != YourSingleton.getInstance(), it would mean that you have two instances of your singleton, which means that YourSingleton isn't singleton at all, which may lead to unpredictable bugs.

However sometimes you need to serialize non-singleton which contains a reference to singleton. The solution is easy:

```
class NonSingleton implements Serializable {
    private transient YourSingleton singleton = YourSingleton.getInstance();
    ...
}
```

With Spring:

```
@Configurable
class NonSingleton implements Serializable {
    @Autowired
    private transient YourSingleton singleton;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Both solutions I mentioned will guarantee that a deserialized singleton == YourSingleton.getInstance(). And yes, of course it won't work with DI managed singletons, because those aren't what's being discussed here at all.

Answer (score 7):

Here below is my `Singleton` class that implements `Serializable` interface. Mark that it contains `readResolve()` method also.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Singleton implements Serializable {

    private static Singleton singleton = new Singleton( );

    public int i = 1;

    private Singleton() { }

    public static Singleton getInstance( ) {

       return singleton;
    }

    public Object readResolve() {
       return getInstance( );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Singleton s1 = getInstance();
        System.out.println(s1.hashCode());

        Singleton s2 = getInstance();
        System.out.println(s2.hashCode());
    }
}
```

Below is the class that will first serialize and then deserialize the above class. Here deserialization takes place two times, but both time only one instance will be created because of readResolve() method.

```
public class SingletonSerializableDemo {

    static Singleton sing = Singleton.getInstance();
    static Singleton s1  = null;
    static Singleton s2 = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
             FileOutputStream fileOut =
             new FileOutputStream("E:/singleton.ser");
             ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
             out.writeObject(sing);
             out.close();
             fileOut.close();
             System.out.println("Serialized data is saved");

             FileInputStream fileIn1 = new FileInputStream("E:/singleton.ser");
             FileInputStream fileIn2 = new FileInputStream("E:/singleton.ser");
             ObjectInputStream in1 = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn1);
             ObjectInputStream in2 = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn2);
             s1 = (Singleton) in1.readObject();
             s2 = (Singleton) in2.readObject();
             System.out.println(s1.hashCode() + " "+ s1.i);
             s1.i = 10;
             System.out.println(s2.hashCode() + " "+ s2.i);
             in1.close();
             in2.close();
             fileIn1.close();
             fileIn2.close();
          }catch(Exception i) {
             i.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
}
```

And the output will be:

Serialized data is saved 
21061094 1 
21061094 10

**Conclusion:** Singleton class can also be serialized by keeping `readResolve()` method in the Singleton class.

Comment: How it overcomes the issue ?

Comment: edit it like java 8, try with resource management

Answer (score 3):

This may be a familiar solution but just in case for reference.

```
public class ConnectionFactory implements Serializable {

    //Static variable for holding singleton reference object
    private static ConnectionFactory INSTANCE;

    /**
     * Private constructor
     */
    private ConnectionFactory() {

    }

    /**
     * Static method for fetching the instance
     *
     * @return
     */
    public static ConnectionFactory getIntance() {
        //Check whether instance is null or not
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            //Locking the class object
            synchronized (ConnectionFactory.class) {
                //Doing double check for the instance
                //This is required in case first time two threads simultaneously invoke
                //getInstance().So when another thread get the lock,it should not create the
                //object again as its already created by the previous thread.
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = new ConnectionFactory();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    /**
     * Special hook provided by serialization where developer can control what object needs to sent.
     * However this method is invoked on the new object instance created by de serialization process.
     *
     * @return
     * @throws ObjectStreamException
     */
    private Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

Testing the code

```
public class SerializationTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConnectionFactory INSTANCE = ConnectionFactory.getIntance();

        try {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("connectFactory.ser"));
            oos.writeObject(INSTANCE);
            oos.close();

            ObjectInputStream osi = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("connectFactory.ser"));
            ConnectionFactory factory1 = (ConnectionFactory) osi.readObject();
            osi.close();

            ObjectInputStream osi2 = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("connectFactory.ser"));
            ConnectionFactory factory2 = (ConnectionFactory) osi2.readObject();
            osi2.close();


            System.out.println("Instance reference check->" + factory1.getIntance());
            System.out.println("Instance reference check->" + factory2.getIntance());
            System.out.println("===================================================");
            System.out.println("Object reference check->" + factory1);
            System.out.println("Object reference check->" + factory2);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Output

```
Instance reference check->com.javabrains.ConnectionFactory@6f94fa3e
Instance reference check->com.javabrains.ConnectionFactory@6f94fa3e
===================================================
Object reference check->com.javabrains.ConnectionFactory@6f94fa3e
Object reference check->com.javabrains.ConnectionFactory@6f94fa3e
```

Answer (score 2):

Let say we have the following singleton class:

```
public class ConnectionFactory implements Serializable {
    private static ConnectionFactory INSTANCE;

    private ConnectionFactory() {  }

    public static ConnectionFactory getInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized(ConnectionFactory.class) {
                if(INSTANCE == null)
                    INSTANCE = new ConnectionFactory();
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Now we have the main class like below for serialising and deserializing objects:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
     ConnectionFactory INSTANCE=ConnectionFactory.getInstance();
     ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("connFactory.ser"));  
     oos.writeObject(INSTANCE);  
     oos.close();

     // Here I am recreating the instance by reading the serialized object data store
     ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("connFactory.ser"));  
     ConnectionFactory factory1 = (ConnectionFactory) ois.readObject();  
     ois.close();  

     // I am recreating the instance AGAIN by reading the serialized object data store
     ObjectInputStream ois2 = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("connFactory.ser"));  
     ConnectionFactory factory2 = (ConnectionFactory) ois2.readObject();  
     ois2.close();

     // Let's see how we have broken the singleton behavior
     System.out.println("Instance reference check->" +factory1.getInstance());
     System.out.println("Instance reference check->" +factory2.getInstance());
     System.out.println("=========================================================");
     System.out.println("Object reference check->" + factory1);
     System.out.println("Object reference check->" + factory2);
}
```

So if we execute above code we will get following behaviour:
**"it has created two objects and one static reference for INSTANCE. That means if we read the serialized format of a singleton object multiple times, we will create multiple objects. This is not what a singleton object is supposed to do. So can we avoid i?, Yes, we can."**

To avoid multiple instances of singleton class we will use following method provided by serialization:

```
private Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
    return INSTANCE;
}
```

This will prevent the creation of multiple instances of a singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

I think Singletons can be serialized and here is the code on how to do it:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class MySingleton implements Serializable {

    private MySingleton(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private static MySingleton mySingleton;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static MySingleton getInstance(String name) {
        if(mySingleton == null) {
            System.out.println("in if...");
            mySingleton = new MySingleton(name);
        }

        return mySingleton;
    }
}
```

and here is "main" method which gets the instance of the Singleton class above,  serializes and de-serializes it:

```
 public static void main (String[] args) {

        MySingleton m = MySingleton.getInstance("Akshay");

        try {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("D://temp.ser"));
            oos.writeObject(m);

            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("D://temp.ser"));
            MySingleton m2 = (MySingleton) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println(m2.getName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

and output is:-

> in if...
>
> Akshay

Thanks.

Comment: But if you compare hashcodes of objects before and after serailization, they are different. Means two new instances get created for a Singleton class! To avoid this use readResolve method in your Singleton class like shown here: `protected Object readResolve() {
        return getInstance(name);
    }`

Comment: Refer below link to know more about readResolve method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html#5903

Comment: while de-serialize object in java, JVM first call default constructor than setter method. if you remove setter method of name, you will get exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer for Breaking the Singleton  class and and how to prevent our class from creating different object by using readResolve() methood;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Singleton implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Singleton() {
}

private static class SingletonHelper {

    private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

}

public static Singleton getInstance() {

    return SingletonHelper.INSTANCE;
}

private Object readResolve() {
    Singleton instance = getInstance();
    return instance;
}
```

}

public class BreakSIngletonUsingSerialization {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    Singleton demo1 =Singleton.getInstance();
    ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/Eclipse/serial.ser"));
    out.writeObject(demo1);
    Singleton demo2 =null;
    ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:/Eclipse/serial.ser"));

    demo2 = (Singleton)in.readObject();

    System.out.println("Hascode demo1 : " +demo1);
    System.out.println("Hascode demo2 : " +demo2);
}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

Singleton classes is just like a manager or controller and in general we do not want to save the state of any controller instead of the entity. Generally we need to save the object state of any entity not the controller.
Singleton is singleton for a single class loader not for multiple class loader. If a class is loaded in a classes loader then the other class loader will not know about it so it behaves like this.