# How should i ideally write Singleton and thread safe class without using any synchronization

Tags: java, thread-safety

I tried writing a Singleton class using eager loading, see my solution below. I have made the constructor private to prevent access and the member field private, too, so it can't be accessed outside class scope.

```
public class Test  {

    private static Test t = new Test();

    private Test() {

    }

    public static Test getInstance() {
        return t;
    }

}
```

So, is this piece thread safe, considering all the scenarios?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Java static initializers thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878577/are-java-static-initializers-thread-safe)

Comment: The answer is the linked duplicate. You should make the static field final, though. Then you're done.

Comment: Use an enum for Singletons. It is that simple. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285520/implementing-singleton-with-an-enum-in-java

Comment: Define _all the scenarios_ as you will still end up with two instances after serialization + deserialization. To fix, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930181/how-to-deal-with-singleton-along-with-serialization)

Comment: @Sebastian thanks, Nico Van Belle, Yes correct i need to write readResolve method to prevent so, i was trying to understand other than using Enums, how we can design singleton well without using any synchronized keywords.

Answer (score 1):

use enum singleton pattern:

```
public enum xxton {
  INSTANCE;
}
```

Since *Singleton Pattern* is about having a private constructor and calling some method to control the instantiations (like some `getInstance`), in Enums we already have an implicit private constructor.

I don't exactly know how the *JVM* or some *container* controls the instances of our `Enums`, but it seems it already use an implicit `Singleton Pattern`, the difference is we don't call a `getInstance`, we just call the Enum.
More generally, you can provide a `readResolve()` method like so:

```
protected Object readResolve() {
  return myInstance;
}
```

Comment: We have many similar answers, already mentioned in question comments section.

Comment: This answer is a mix with copy/pasted answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930181/how-to-deal-with-singleton-along-with-serialization) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285520/implementing-singleton-with-an-enum-in-java). Flagging it for admins